# React CRA - meta og tags for specific page (Spring Boot)

Tags: reactjs, facebook-opengraph, react-helmet

We want links to be shared across social media which display a preview image of the page. This image can be different every time. Our app is a CRA with client side rendering and a Java Spring Boot backend.

Is this possible? SEO isn't important to us at all as it's a B2B product. I've added React Helmet to the page in question. I've read that SSR is used for this but our application isn't built or intended to be this way so we would like to keep it as is. We only need the OG meta tag for one page so it's more of an exception than a rule. A contrived example is below:

```
const userData = useGetUser();

<Helmet>
    <MainContainer>
        <Box>{userData?.name}</Box>
        <Box>{userData?.image}</Box>
     </MainContainer>
     <meta property="og:image" content={userData?.image} />
</Helmet>
```

If anybody knows how to get this working I'd really appreciate it. Thanks all!

Comment: You don't have to have SSR. Simply add your head tags inside `<Helmet>`, as shown in the project [`README`](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet).

Comment: Would it work for dynamic images? I just need to display the an image in the link preview for social media, but the image could be different each time.

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't work. I think it must need SSR...

Comment: Facebook and some of the messaging applications [cache](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/images/#precaching) the Open Graph data for a specific URL, including the image, rather than querying the website each time they want to show the information. If you do change your image, those applications won’t be aware of the change unless you use their [rescrape tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/). One other note – Facebook doesn’t show an image the first time a URL is shared unless you have the image dimensions in the OG metadata.

Answer (score 1):

React Helmet adds the following attribute at the end of every tag that you specify as a child of the `<Helmet/>` component:

```html
data-react-helmet="true"
```

So this:

```
<Helmet>
  <meta property="og:image" content="image link" />
</Helmet>
```

renders into:

```html
<head>
  <meta property="og:image" content="image link" data-react-helmet="true">
</head>
```

This invalidates the meta tags for the online sharing preview debug tools, such as Facebook's [Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and https://www.opengraph.xyz/.

If this attribute is removed, the link to your site displays as expected in the above mentioned validation tools.

There's an [open issue](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/79) to remove this attribute from the tags generated via React Helmet.